# Terraform nat gateway AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, resources, aws-nat-gateway

I am trying to create nat gateway from terraform by using AWS as provider but subnet_id in resource aws_nat_gateway always gives me error. I am trying to assign public subnet in subnet_id on resource "aws_nat_gateway" "sample_nat_gateway" from variables.tf file  but failing in doing so and need support if someone can assist ?

Below is my vpc.tf file of vpc module

```
 resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet" {
  for_each = var.prefix
 
  availability_zone_id = each.value["az"]
  cidr_block = each.value["cidr"]
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.sample_vpc.id     
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-${each.value["az"]}"
 }
}
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "sample_nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.sample_eip.id
  subnet_id      = ""
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-sample-nat-gateway"
    Environment = var.environment
}
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.sample_igw]
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "prefix" {
   type = map
   default = {
      sub-1 = {
         az = "use2-az1"
         cidr = "10.0.1.0/16"
      }
      sub-2 = {
         az = "use2-az2"
         cidr = "10.0.2.0/24"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: │ Error: Missing resource instance key
│ 
│   on ../modules/vpc/vpc.tf line 108, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "sample_nat_gateway":
│  108:   subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public-subnet.id
│ 
│ Because aws_subnet.public-subnet has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_subnet.public-subnet[each.key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subent's **can't be empty** You have to provide valid subnet id where the NAT is going to be placed. For example:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "sample_nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.sample_eip.id

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public-subnet["sub-1"].id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-sample-nat-gateway"
    Environment = var.environment
}
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.sample_igw]
}
```

where `aws_subnet.example` is one of the public subnets in your VPC.

Comment: thanks it is working fine. Also can you please confirm how can I get these sub-1 and sub-2 values in output variables and use these values in other modules where I created EC2 instances from launch configurations in autsocaling group resource  resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "sample_asg_1               vpc_zone_identifier       = [var.subnet_id]

Comment: @Abdulrehman If my answer helped, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated. For your new issue, I would suggest making new question with relevant details.

Comment: yes it is correct thanks. I have voted as well. Please let me know if anything else require from my side

Comment: @Abdulrehman Thanks. To accept the answer you have to press a tick-like button as shown here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979

Comment: completed thanks for your feedback